# Does treating a cohen's blemish permit him to serve?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, kohen-priest, temple-service-avoda

The Rambam lists 140 blemishes that invalidate a cohen from serving (Hilchot Biyat Mikdash, perek 8). There are some that appear to be genetic traits that cannot be (easily) treated without extensive surgery. However, some seem treatable, especially with the technology of today.

In [8:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Admission_into_the_Sanctuary.8.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the Rambam states that a man born with a sixth finger (with no bone) can cut off that sixth finger and he is "kosher" to serve. Other than this the Rambam offers no solution or work-around that gives a person the opportunity to treat the blemish in order to serve.

Once a person has one of these 140 blemishes is there a way that that person can treat the blemish in order to serve in the bet hamikdash?

Comment: Anyone in touch with any posek adar? :)

Comment: Maybe the blemish becomes a Mum Over thanks to new treatments.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Talmud Bavli, Tractate Megillah (I cannot recall the exact pages) states that a cohen is only restricted from serving if the blemish is not known among the people, and will distract them. In our modern day, where knowledge of different types of mild blemishes is much more well known and "not a big deal", I suspect that it may be the case that some of these restrictions no longer apply and the cohen would be allowed to serve even without treatment. I have no authority that says this, however - I'm applying (possibly flawed) logic.

Comment: @Benyamin thanks for this. I had also heard this from somewhere and cannot recall where, i.e., the avodah is for the observation of the public, if the cohen is belmished it could distract the general public from the avodah itself. It would seem that these laws would be applied differently today, by this logic, if correct.

Comment: megillah 24: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.24b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en